# Does anyone know how to install fluidsynth or pyfluidsynth on windows 10? AttributeError: module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute 'Synth'

Tags: python, midi, fluidsynth

I've tried to install fluidsynth and pyfluidsynth on windows 10 so many times in order to let magenta.music function play_sequence(note_seq,synth=mm.fluidsynth) play a note sequence and show it on my jupyter notebook.

I tried to clone the github repository, install it with pip, but nothing seems to work. I check that Synth class was on my fluidsynth.py script and I found it so I don't know where is the problem.

The error I get is this one:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 #MIDI file from raw pitch curve
      3 file = 'midi
----> 4 midi_pianoroll(file)
      5 play_midi(file + '.mid')

in midi_pianoroll(file_prefix)
     16 
     17     # This is a colab utility method that plays a NoteSequence.
---> 18     mm.play_sequence(note_seq,synth=mm.fluidsynth)
     19     return
     20

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\magenta\music\notebook_utils.py in play_sequence(sequence, synth, sample_rate, colab_ephemeral, **synth_args)
     99     **synth_args: Additional keyword arguments to pass to the synth function.
    100   """
--> 101   array_of_floats = synth(sequence, sample_rate=sample_rate, **synth_args)
    102 
    103   try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\magenta\music\midi_synth.py in fluidsynth(sequence, sample_rate, sf2_path)
     53   """
     54   midi = midi_io.note_sequence_to_pretty_midi(sequence)
---> 55   return midi.fluidsynth(fs=sample_rate, sf2_path=sf2_path)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pretty_midi\pretty_midi.py in fluidsynth(self, fs, sf2_path)
    916         # Get synthesized waveform for each instrument
    917         waveforms = [i.fluidsynth(fs=fs,
--> 918                                   sf2_path=sf2_path) for i in self.instruments]
    919         # Allocate output waveform, with #sample = max length of all waveforms
    920         synthesized = np.zeros(np.max([w.shape[0] for w in waveforms]))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pretty_midi\pretty_midi.py in (.0)
    916         # Get synthesized waveform for each instrument
    917         waveforms = [i.fluidsynth(fs=fs,
--> 918                                   sf2_path=sf2_path) for i in self.instruments]
    919         # Allocate output waveform, with #sample = max length of all waveforms
    920         synthesized = np.zeros(np.max([w.shape[0] for w in waveforms]))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pretty_midi\instrument.py in fluidsynth(self, fs, sf2_path)
    426 
    427         # Create fluidsynth instance
--> 428         fl = fluidsynth.Synth(samplerate=fs)
    429         # Load in the soundfont
    430         sfid = fl.sfload(sf2_path)

AttributeError: module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute 'Synth'

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you have to:

1. Build it:
   https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/BuildingWithCMake#building-with-msys2-on-windows
   (cause it is installed on os, not on python)
2. Then in your IDE terminal (let's say PyCharm) type:
   pip install --upgrade pyfluidsynth
3. You can also install pretty_midi for later usage (pip install pretty_midi)

Answer (score 0):

I am just now, trying the instructions from here:
[https://ksvi.mff.cuni.cz/~dingle/2019/prog_1/python_music.html](https://ksvi.mff.cuni.cz/%7Edingle/2019/prog_1/python_music.html)

the package is here:
https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/releases/tag/v2.1.0.rc1